# Changing the grid view on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide my screen into grid in responsive way and want to display grid items in stylish way.

I used Bootstrap css for responsive page and created grid like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/bc954zLq/2/

code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1"  />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/2" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/3" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/4" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/4" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 well rowCell">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/4" />

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now issue is how can I make grid item interactive `on hover`

Is it possible to create this style for grid items in fiddle?

http://metcreative.com/demo_viewer/index.php?theme=santone

Comment: Please provide your own code/attempts. What have you tried?

Comment: using css3 transitions its possible

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: possible attempts I have created in that grid

Comment: anyone else finds bootstrap code so ugly that you don't even want to read?

Comment: @Claudiu: Apologize, but I am not css guy, I appreciate if you can suggest improvements

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/bc954zLq/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/bc954zLq/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/bc954zLq/4/) is what I managed to do so far.I used jquery and change display of description.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(
        function(){
           $(this).siblings('.description').css('display','block');
        },
        function(){
           $(this).siblings('.description').css('display','none');
       }
    );
});
```

Update: I used @Claudiu answer to compelete mine.[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/bc954zLq/7/) is a compelete version

Comment: I updated my answer to a more complete one.check it ;) and your are welcome ! :)

Comment: I was also thought to use Claudiu answer with yours. Still I dont know why the navigation does not look like `santone` themse in my questeion. I dont realized what difference they have used for such smoother and decent look

Answer (score 0):

To create that effect you need transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/bc954zLq/3/

If you add this you will see an effect like the one you want. But you will also need to insert some html in your `.rowCell`, text to appear beneath.

```
.rowCell {
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.rowCell:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-45px);
}
.rowCell img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```